# If $A$ and $Q$ are unitary, then $U = Q^{-1}AQ$ is unitary...

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Here is what I have so far...

Since $A$ and $Q$ are unitary, by definition, we have that $AA^* = A^*A = I$ and $QQ^* = Q^*Q = I$, in other words, $A^* = A^{-1}$ and $Q^* = Q^{-1}$. We can then define $U = Q^*AQ$. We want to show that $U$ is unitary, namely, $UU^* = U^*U = I$. So,

$$UU^* = (Q^*AQ)(Q^*AQ)^* = (Q^*AQ)(QA^*Q^*) = \dots$$

This is where I am lost since I have no reason to assume that $Q^2 = I$.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mistake is $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$ so $(Q^*AQ)^*=Q^*A^*Q$.

This implies that $UU^*=(Q^*AQ)(Q^*AQ)^*=Q^*AQQ^*A^*Q=I$.

Comment: Of course, socks-shoes property. Thanks!